# Python script breaks after resetting model poses

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a python script to move a robot to a certain position, reset model poses and loop this process n times. However, after first reset, I obtain a message:    [WallTime: 1500641282.768572] [0.001000] ROS time moved backwards: 2089.084s.

I was wondering if there is a way to deal with the time problem, as I do not care what time it is in my program.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267047/python-script-breaks-after-resetting-model-poses/) by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have realized, that while /gazebo/reset_simulation resets the clock, we can use /gazebo/reset_world, which only resets the poses.

---

Originally posted by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) with karma: 52 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
Could you please just accept your own answer instead of closing the question? Thanks.

And a tip: for questions that are really Gazebo specific, I would recommend posting on `answers.gazebosim.org`, not here.